# Generate an image that can be most easily detected by Computer Vision algorithms

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection, feature-extraction

Working on a small side project related to Computer Vision, mostly to try playing around with OpenCV. It lead me to an interesting question:

Using feature detection to find known objects in an image isn't always easy- objects are hard to find, especially if the features of the target object aren't great.

But if I could choose ahead of time what it is I'm looking for, then in theory I could generate for myself an optimal image for detection. Any quality that makes feature detection hard would be absent, and all the qualities that make it easy would exist.

I suspect this sort of thought went into things like QR codes, but with the limitations that they wanted QR codes to be simple, and small.

So my question for you: How would you generate an optimal image for later recognition by a camera? What if you already know that certain problems like skew, or partial obscuring would occur?

Thanks very much

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about [fiducial markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiducial_marker).

Comment: @Sneftel: Pretty much. Can one generate a really optimal Fiducial marker in order to handle the many problems generally associated with using cameras to find things in the real world?

Comment: Yes. One relies on the robustness of corner detection and of relative orientations, essentially producing a fiducial whose information is independent of rotation and skew. It's a huge topic, integrating trigonometry with information theory.

Comment: You're right to think of QR codes, BTW. They're too detailed to make good fiducials for most purposes, but most fiducials look like low-res QR codes, because they share most of the same needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like AR markers.
Take a look at [ArToolkit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/), [ArToolkitPlus](http://handheldar.icg.tugraz.at/artoolkitplus.php) or [Aruco](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) libraries, they have marker generators and detectors. 
And papeer about marker generation: http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/sites/default/files/GarridoJurado2014.pdf

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need- that paper especially is really fantastic. It only handles ﬁducial markers that are made of black and white boxes, but it does get that idea I've had in my head: maximum entropy between the different markers for easier recognition.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you plan to use feature detection, than marker should be specific to used feature detector. Common practice for detector design is good response to "corners" or regions with high x,y gradients. Also you should note the scaling of target.
2. The simplest detection can be performed with BLOBS. It can be faster and more robust than feature points. For example you can detect circular blobs or rectangular.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distance you want to see your markers from and viewing conditions/backgrounds you typically use and camera resolution/noise you should choose different images/targets. Under moderate perspective from a longer distance a color target is pretty unique, see this:

https://surf-it.soe.ucsc.edu/sites/default/files/velado_report.pdf

at close distances various bar/QR codes may be a good choice. Other than that any flat textured object will be easy to track using homography as opposed to 3D objects. 
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html

Even different views of 3d objects can be quickly learned and tracked by such systems as Predator:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GhNXHCQGsM

then comes the whole field of hardware, structured light, synchronized markers, etc, etc. Kinect, for example, uses a predefined pattern projected on the surface to do stereo. This means it recognizes and matches million of micro patterns per second creating a depth map from the matched correspondences. Note that one camera  sees the pattern and while another device - a projector generates it working as a virtual camera, see
http://article.wn.com/view/2013/11/17/Apple_to_buy_PrimeSense_technology_from_the_360s_Kinect/

The quickest way to demonstrate good tracking of a standard checkerboard pattern is to use pNp function of open cv:

[http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=public:cameracalibration_detecting_fieldcorners_of_a_chessboard.gif](http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=public%3acameracalibration_detecting_fieldcorners_of_a_chessboard.gif)

this literally can be done by calling just two functions

```
found = findChessboardCorners(src, chessboardSize, corners, camFlags);
drawChessCornersDots(dst, chessboardSize, corners, found);
```

To sum up, your question is very broad and there are multiple answers and solutions. Formulate your viewing condition, camera specs, backgrounds, distances, amount of motion and perspective you expect to have indoors vs outdoors, etc. There is no such a thing as a general average case in computer vision!